# How to fix maximum call stack size exceeded error in angular 11?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have 2 modules in angular 11

1. CustomerModule
2. AccountingModule

and declare some component as widget component in these modules that used in each other

1. CustomerModule -> CustomerBlockInfoWidget
2. AccountingModule -> AccountingBalanceWidget

now want to use CustomerBlockInfoWidget in AccountingModule
and AccountingBalanceWidget in CustomerModule

and finally, I have the infinity load and get Maximum call stack size exceeded error

now how I can use these widgets that fix the infinity load

Comment: move your both components in a `sharedModule` and then use these components in any module. just import `sharedModule` in your desired modules where you want to use these components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Maximum call stack size exceeded` error is always a symptom of an infinite loop. The provided information doesn't point to a possible place in the code that triggers it.

It might be a simple loop with no chance for an exit or a more complex scenario like Function A calls Function B which calls Function C which calls Function A and here it goes again.

If you have a call stack of the error, reading it should be enough to notice this infinite execution.

Answer (score 7):

Please make sure that you did not add any components, directives, and pipes in the import array of modules.

### NOTE

**You can add standalone components, directives, and pipes in the import array of the module.**

Answer (score 2):

In may case, I accidentally included my component to import instead of export. the
commented part was causing the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pm7PM.png)

Comment: Hi, please read  [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)